# ASP.NET ListBox: Display both text & value?

Tags: asp.net, text, listbox

I have a listbox on my aspx page.

I'd like it to display both the text and associated values (not the index). So if I were to add items like this

```
Dim this As ListItem = New ListItem("Horse", "2")
Dim that As ListItem = New ListItem("Dog", "3")

me.ListBox.Items.Add(this)
me.ListBox.Items.Add(that)
```

my listbox would look something like this (please excuse my list of artistic talent):

```
--------------
|2 Horse     |
|3 Dog       |
--------------
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Why would you want to show a number that to an end user means nothing though?  That is the whole purpose of `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem.Text`

Comment: @JonH: True, but we don't know that the number has no meaning to _his_ users :)

Comment: @Tom, thanks for that -- in the <insert adjective for 'poorly designed' here> arena I work in, the value actually has meaning to my users. Of course, now I feel like a total idiot for not thinking about concatenation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not just combine the text and the value into a variable.

```
Dim nextItem as ListItem = New ListItem(String.Concat("2", " ", "Horse"), "2")

ListBox.Items.Add(nextItem)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the ID as part of the item text?

```
Dim this As ListItem = New ListItem("2 Horse", "2")
Dim that As ListItem = New ListItem("3 Dog", "3")
```